# Efficiently passing a large chunk of data to Tokio tasks?

Tags: rust-tokio

I'm generating programmatically in an application around 1GB of data, which after generating it never changes. I then have hundreds of parallel tasks that need to access the data in a read-only fashion, but there's high contention for it.

Does Rust have a way of handing such a scenario efficiently? In other words, at a high-level I have something like:

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
  let data = generate_large_vector();

  for _ in 1..N {
    // Do something with the data
    tokio::spawn(...);
  }
}
```

I would not like to copy the whole buffer for each task, since I will run out of memory and it's also inefficient CPU cache usage. Protecting the whole vector with a mutex also adds lots of contention.

Is there an efficient way to handle this? In C++ I would just give the data as a const to each thread.

The problem here is the lifetime of the data, so the borrow checker doesn't let me hand over a slice to it. Is there a way to spawn tasks that don't outlive the scope where they started, so that the borrow checker will allow me to pass references?

Comment: When you own a Vec, you hold a pointer to data on the heap. There's no overhead when you move it since you're just moving a pointer and some length data and stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use `std::sync::OnceLock` when I have some global immutable data.

```rust
use std::sync::OnceLock;

static BIG_VEC: OnceLock<Vec<u8>> = OnceLock::new();

fn big_vec() -> &'static Vec<u8> {
    BIG_VEC.get_or_init(generate_large_vector)
}

fn generate_large_vector() -> Vec<u8> {
    todo!()
}

async fn task_a() {
    let huge = big_vec();
}

async fn task_b() {
    let massive = big_vec();
}
```